# Name for light fixture tube socket (tombstone) retainers?

Tags: light-fixture, fluorescent, lamp-tombstone

What are the names of the metal photographed parts?  The tombstones are inserted to clarify function.

I would like to order more of these metal parts, however, I do not know the terminology to Google for them. There are two different though similar parts:

[image]

[image]

Comment: I assume the metal parts don't have any part # stamped into them? Do you know the manufacturer? These are probably not standard parts but that doesn't mean they'd be impossible to find..

Comment: Correct: they do not have part # stamped

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your terminology is correct: they're called tombstone (or bi-pin) fluorescent lampholders. In particular, those in the photo are `locking` or `turn-type`, a nice safety feature that makes it less likely for a lamp to fall out of the socket. A search at Amazon.com for `Fluorescent Tombstone Lampholder` found more than 30 similar devices.

**N.B.** There are *two* types, shorting and non-shorting, also called [shunted and non-shunted](https://insights.regencylighting.com/shunted-vs.-non-shunted-sockets-tombstones-lampholders). Be sure you examine your socket (you may need to pop off a plastic cover) and get the same type. Also, if you're converting from fluorescent to LED, check the type needed for the replacement tubes -- it might be different from your current lampholders.

Comment: Thanks for the response: the feedback indicates I needed to reword the question because I am seeking to buy the metal fixture that hosts the tombstone

Comment: Just a fixture. I have never seen the metal "fixture" parts sold seperately. Usually you need to get a set from the specific manufacturer.

Comment: If you cant find the identical fixture, it looks like it would be easy to cut and bend from sheet metal. What look like long ventilation holes would be unneeded if you were to remove the ballast when relamping with LED's.

Answer (score 1):

I am only guessing here ... I'd describe them as tombstone bases if I were ordering over the phone. Maybe "tombstone brackets"? Sounds more official. Wouldn't it be cheaper and less trouble simply to buy a new complete fixture?

Comment: I was able to find spare parts by taking down a rusty old fixture, sanding and repainting.  The reason that I am avoiding a new fixture is because there is a large existing array of fixtures and it is easier (and keeps the array consistent) to simply replace the missing tombstone mounts.

Answer (score 1):

I have never seen just the ends being sold. I have seen "bare" fixtures ie no ballast for ~10$ at places like 1000bulbs.com I believe they came with t8/t12 style non shunted tombstones.

Comment: Nice!  The fixtures I saw were single ended.  Wondering if there are dual-ended bare fixtures?

Comment: The ones I purchased I wired up for dual, I prefer dual ended over single at work because fixtures regularly get clobbered by flying chunks of wood, having direct wired single ended tubes makes me nervous.

Comment: Agreed: I only use dual ended for safety reasons.  Any links you can offer up to dual ended and post them in your response above?  Much appreciated!